# Swift: send POST request with JSONEncoder encoded data does not work

Tags: json, swift, jsonserializer, urlsession

I am using the JSONEncoder that has been provided with Swift4.
I have a class called Customer that uses the Codable protocol. Inside of Customer there are four Strings.

```
class Customer: Codable {

   var title: String
   var firstName: String
   var lastName: String
   var email: String
}
```

Reading JSON with a GET Request works fine.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
       print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
    guard let data = data else { return }

    do {       
       let customer = try JSONDecoder().decode(Customer.self, from: data)
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          print("\(customer.title)")
          print("\(customer.firstName)")
          print("\(customer.lastName)")
          print("\(customer.email)")                  
       }

    } catch let jsonError {
       print(jsonError)
    }
}.resume()
```

However when I start to do a POST request I am lost:

First set up the request object:

```
let urlString = "http://localhost:8000/customer"
guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let customer = Customer()
customer.title = "Mr"
customer.firstName = "Chuck"
customer.lastName = "Norris"
customer.email = "chuck.norris@awsome.com"

let encodedData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(customer)
print(String(data: encodedData!, encoding: .utf8)!) //<- Looks as intended
// Output is {"firstName":"Chuck","lastName":"Norris","title":"MR","email":"chuck.norris@awesome.com "}
```

Now send it out

```
request.httpBody = encodedData // 
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    if let response = response {
        print(response)
    }
    if let data = data {
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: [])
            print(json)
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
})
```

In return I receive the message "The given data was not valid JSON."

So, my assumption is that I simply can not just put the encoded JSON data into the http body of my request.

Browsing through some articles about URLSession and JSON I found that it seems that I need to serialize my encoded JSON:

```
var json: Any?
if let data = encodedData {
    json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
}
```

Now, I don't know how to proceed. First I do not understand why I should serialize my JSON to something that can not simply put into a httpBody. 
Because JSONSerialization.jsonObject produces Any? and not Data.

**Update**
Now, I was able to successfully send my data to my server. I am still trying to understand what was wrong - because I did not changed anything (except for the removal of the JSONSerialization call inside the completion Handler. I will investigate further...
...And .resume had been missing. :-)

Comment: Can you debug the server results?

Comment: `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject:options:)` returns `Any?`, because it could respond nil (not valid), Dictionary or Array. That's why it's Any. It's unclear what's your error (where you get it), but could you give us the value returned there `//<- Looks as intended`?

Comment: I mean debug the server application to check the results

Comment: In the very first approximation your code should work

Comment: Don't know if that matters your `Application/json` content type is generally `application/json`